# ProtocolViolationException while sending POST request

Tags: c#, rest, http-post

I have read other similar questions and tried the solutions from those questions, but since that did not work, hence I am posting this here.

When I send POST request below, it fails with the following error message:

```
System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   ....
   ....
```

My GET requests for other URL end points are working fine, I am only having this issue while issuing a POST request. Also, I have already set the ContentLength in the code appropriately. I am still unable to send the POST request. Thoughts?

```
public void TestSubmitJobWithParams1()
    {
        const string RestActionPath = "URL_GOES_HERE";

        // if you have multipe parameters seperate them with teh '&' delimeter.
        var postData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("MaxNumberOfRowsPerSFSTask") + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("3000");

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RestActionPath);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Timeout = 150000;
        request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


        string output = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
                {
                    output = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                using (var stream = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    output = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            else if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
            {
                output = "Request timeout is expired.";
            }
        }
        catch (ProtocolViolationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want ASCII encoding? That's going to turn any character with a code above 127 into a question mark. That would cause your program to fail for pretty much any locale other than U.S. English, and quite possibly for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

Firstly, you don't need to set `ContentLength` directly - just leave it out (defaults to -1).  You're actually calling it twice, so remove both calls.

Also, you need to call `Close()` on the stream before calling `GetResponse()`

```
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();

newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newStream.Close();
```

Alternatively, you could have it within a using statement, which handles the closing and disposal for you):

```
using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

You also don't technically need to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` for the `postData` since there's nothing in your string that would violate a Url's integrity. Just do:

```
string postData = "MaxNumberOfRowsPerSFSTask=3000");
```

Let me know if that solves it for you.

For a more thorough rundown, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Specifically, the section about `ProtocolViolationException` and also where it says:

> When using the POST method, you must get the request stream, write the data to be posted, and close the stream. This method blocks waiting for content to post; if there is no time-out set and you do not provide content, the calling thread blocks indefinitely.